# What is the purpose of Webpack's entry.main?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm looking over the source code found in sound-redux, a repo found here on github: https://github.com/andrewngu/sound-redux. While looking through the webpack.config.js I wasn't able to figure out what entry.main was doing.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  entry: {
    main: [
        './scripts/main.js',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'
    ]
  }
  // ...
}
```

What is actually happening here and how is this being used by this app? The documentation is completely silent on this feature as far as I could find.

Answer (score 2):

The `entry` inside `module.exports` signifies the entry point of the application. Now what `main` is is an example of multiple entry points. `main` is the key for the array in the object of entry point paths and is used as a name. Consider this Webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: {
        app: ['./path/to/main.js', './somewhere/else/index.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: "to/somewhere",
        filename: "[name].js"
    }
    ...
}
```

What this will do is set an entry point to an application to multiple files for [Code Splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) and output to a single JS file named `app.js`, due to the label given, `app`.

Read more about it at the [Webpack Docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
    {
     context: __dirname + "/app",
     entry: "./entry",
     output: {
         path: __dirname + "/dist",
         filename: "bundle.js"
     }
  }
```

entry is the entry point for the bundle. If you pass a string: The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup. So here in above example context: __dirname + "/app" is the directory of entry point and entry: "./entry" is the entry file name. The output of will be a bundle file filename: "bundle.js". You can give any name to bundle file.

**Nicely explained here**

http://ui-codeman.blogspot.in/2017/02/webpack.html?view=sidebar